# How to find signal slot relationship in Qt?

Tags: qt, signals, connect, slot, moc

I am recently new to Qt but I have to understand and modify a huge Qt project by someone else.
Is it possible to check the signal slot connection relationship from the source code without finding all the corresponding connect() function?
I heard that the MOC file stores this information somewhere, but I cannot find them out.

Comment: I believe that looking at moc files will not help you a lot. With Qt Creator feature "Find usage" you should investigate project faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking only for MOC file then you can find it in debug directory. This Directory will be created at same location where your project is located. You need to compiles your code in Qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the build directory, for every header file that have a class that inherit QObject, moc will generate a cpp file that has a moc_* prefix.
Ex.: ClassA.h -> moc_ClassA.cpp

Comment: Sorry, I mean I can find the moc files but I don't really understand how to get the connection information from there.